# Defining css for a specific element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#top">
                <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>  !!!!!!!!!!!!
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'm trying to define a css that will only affect the `<a>` element with the '!' symbols. 
The CSS I'm trying is:

```
.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-brand a { something }
```

This CSS won't affect this  element and I have no idea why...

Comment: The <a>. Also, what if I wanted to do the CSS based on some class that will be added dynamically, say, navbar-collapsed being added to the <nav>, do I have to do anything special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting the space before the last class selector, as `.navbar-brand` is a child of the element with the classes `.navbar-custom` and `.navbar-fixed-top` you need to insert a space before it.

The second issue is taht the `.navbar-brand` is the class of the `<a>` element so you need to do this :

```
.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top a.navbar-brand { something }
```

For more information about the descentdant selector (space) to select the child of an element please see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors#Summary)

Comment: correct answer, and it's probably worth clarifying the difference here: spaces designate general descendents. if you leave out the space, you are selecting for an element that has both classes at the same time.

Comment: Is there a way to debug and see what classes does the element have in real time?

Comment: @Tsury you can use the dev tools in your browser to inspect the DOM in realtime

Comment: I don't know what else is messing with it but it only works when I remove the 'a' from the end of the first line...

Comment: This worked for some reason: .navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top a.navbar-brand { something }

Comment: @Tsury aha! yes that is because the `.navbar-brand` is the class of the `<a>` element and not a parent of it.

Comment: GOP Wins it again! (Guess Oriented Programming)